# PyCharm cannot call programs from CMD Path

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a code that needs to call a program from with a CMD command. 
When I run the code in Python IDLE, it works, but not on Pycharm.

Here is an example code:

```
import os
os.system('pip')
```

This code runs on python IDLE, but on Pycharm it exits with:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am running it on Windows Server 2012 R2 if that helps. 
How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you run your code in `cmd`? Maybe you can't add `c:\python27\scripts` to environment variable 'PATH' ,

Comment: If I go to CMD and type the code, it works...

Comment: Every `CMD` may use different `PATH` variable and search files in  different folders. So maybe you have to use full path or you have to set `PATH` somewhere in PyCharm settings.

Comment: Did you  set `PATH` environment variable? Or you can use absolute path to call a program.

Comment: How do I do that for PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

@Litwos,

`pip` should be bundled with your python interpreter - if PyCharm can find your python interpreter, it should be able to find a workable `pip`. Check that your python interpreter is set properly and PyCharm can find all the bundled tools.

Note: I have to do this for every new project:

1. Open PyCharm Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter
2. Select an appropriate interpreter
3. Verify that `pip` shows in the package list below the Project Interpreter listbox